# Does flowing or turbulent air affect gas sensors such as PM2.5 Laser dust sensors and NDIR sensors?

Tags: sensor, laser, drone, gas-sensor, air-pressure

My project is to place a laser dust sensor to detect PM2.5 and an NDIR gas detector on a drone to measure air quality. My understanding is that these sensors work by shining a laser through a channel of air and measuring the laser with a detector after passing through the channel. The movement of the drone and turbulence from the propellors could push air into the air channel of the sensor. Would this ruin the measurement? I could not find any information on the topic. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your question is unrelated to electronics/electrical engineering as defined by this site.

Comment: I've seen manufacturers recommend keeping air still around these sensors. Not sure if the physical basis from this recommendation, but if whoever makes your sensors doesn't have more info it would be easy enough to test if air motion changes the reading.